# CENTOS 6.9 php soap extension installed but not working

Tags: php, soap, centos, cpanel

I have VPS server on OVH with:
CENTOS 6.9 kvm v68.0.27, WHM and cPanel

When I use SoapClient get error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/kowal/public_html/[...]
```

I successfully installed soap php extension as root

> yum install php-soap

Then go to  **WHM** -> **MultiPHP INI Editor**
and found statement

```
;;;;
; Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
; found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.
;;;;
```

I look into /etc/php.d and in this direcotory is soap.ini and there are files:

```
curl.ini      fileinfo.ini  json.ini      phar.ini      soap.ini      zip.ini
```

soap.ini contain
extension=soap.so

when I run

```
php -m | grep -i soap
```

It return nothing.

My PHP script still return error "Class 'SoapClient' not found"

I did restart apache service even restart server.

--- EDIT ---

I have multiphp on my server, and I think that's why yum install php-soap doesn't make any change.

I found that there is *ea-php70-php-soap.x86_64* packake available for install and run

```
yum install ea-php70-php-soap.x86_64
```

but it gives me error:

```
Protected multilib versions: ea-php70-php-common-7.0.27-1.1.3.cpanel.i686 != ea-php70-php-common-7.0.27-5.5.5.cpanel.x86_64
```

I try same with "yum install ea-php70-php-soap.i686" with same result

and I really don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is /etc the folder that /home/kowal uses for its php.ini? If you have a newer webmin then the etc/php.ini your site uses may be in the /home/kowal directory.

Comment: Yes. phpinfo(); returns configuration including declaration with soap extension

Additional .ini files parsed: [...], /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/soap.ini

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: for this account in cPanel I have ea-php70 but there is aslo php55 and php56 available on the server.

Comment: That is very peculiar. If I were you I would maybe test with php 5.5 and see if it works there. If so, then something may be wrong with the php 7 install/version you are using.